# Detect test is being run by ReSharper Continuous Testing

Tags: c#, testing, resharper

I am using [ReSharper Continuous Testing](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/11/19/continuous-testing-in-dotcover-and-resharper-ultimate/)  and want to write some code (c#) that can run a custom scenario when a test is being run by the r# Continuous Testing engine. ie not being run explcitly by the user

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such possibility now. Continuous Testing test runner process and test runner process started manually are identical.